# I want to generate a QR code with python that automatically redirects me to a website after scanning

Tags: python, html, web, qr-code

is it possible to generate a QR code for a url that will automatically redirect to the website instead of  just showing me the url link after scanning?

```
import qrcode
from PIL import Image

# Define a function to generate the dynamic QR code
def generate_dynamic_qr_code(website_url):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(website_url)
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    return img

# Define the URL you want to encode
website_url =  "https://www.nielsentam.tv/#/sa-join-the-panel"

# Generate the dynamic QR code
dynamic_qr_code = generate_dynamic_qr_code(website_url)

# Save the QR code as an image
dynamic_qr_code.save("C:/Users/nymaswan2201/Downloads/qrcode.png")


print("done")
```

Comment: QR codes only encode a piece of data. How it is handled by scanning device is entirely up to this device.

Comment: I see. Makes sense to keep devices secure.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect it's impossible for security reasons.

QR codes just contain information; they can't compel the user to do an action. Like words or books.

You can try social engineering like adding threats or exclamation marks to your message; maybe then the user will go to the relevant site.

Comment: I had the same suspicion but I wanted to make sure either way.